# CSS3 translate issue Overflow

Tags: css, translate, webkit-transform

First of all, here is a jsfiddle to illustrate my issue : http://jsfiddle.net/EKxkx/
I don't know why on jsfiddle, the css translate is only working on chrome, but on the live version the issue is only visible under firefox as shown here : http://helveticventure.com/startupweekend/v4/test.html

I'm using the ez-css framework (ez-css.org). With the following layout :

```
----------
|   1    |
----------
|   |    |
| 2 |  3 |
|   |    |
----------
|   4    |
----------
```

When I put a -webkit-transform: translate(0, 30px); to both the block 2 and 3, they don't behave the same way.

The block 3 is moving under the block 4 when the block 2 is moving above the block 4.
The behavior I want to archive is the on used by block 3. Both block moving below the block 4. But I really don't know how.

Thanks for your help!

Eric

Comment: are you looking more for an explanation of the bug or for a workarond?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why I get this behaviors, to eventually be able to find a workaround.

Comment: So as a workaround define `position: relative` to block `#4` or use `overflow:hidden` on container of blocks `#2` and `#3` (I tried both on latest chrome)

Comment: +1 for the linked site that made me laugh A LOT :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fabrizio Calderan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098851/fabrizio-calderan)'s answer worked perfectly!

http://jsfiddle.net/kXySp/

I've added :

```
.ez-last{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.ez-fl{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

And know the bloc 2 is moving below the block 4.

Eric